# Using existing android sdk on Android Studio 0.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I have latest SDK(v22.0.4) and SDK tools(v17) for Android already.
And I installed Android Studio v0.2.1.
I want to use single SDK for Android Studio and others(Eclipse, IntelliJ..).
So I was trying to add the SDK to Android Studio, but I can't create a new project with the existing SDK.

Failed to import Gradle project: could not fetch model of type "IdeaProject" using Gradle distribution 'http://serivces.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
A problem occurred configuring project':HelloAndroid'
A problem occurred configuring project':HelloAndroid'
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuation ':HelloAndroid:_DebugCompile'.
Could not find any version the matches com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+
Required by:
  HelloAndroid:HelloAndroid:unspecified

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the SDK that you're trying to use, be sure that the Android Support Repository is installed. That repository is what is used to download the latest support libraries as referenced by your Maven artifact `com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+`.

Comment: Thank you.  I hate myself for not finding this out sooner.